# Confused about Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, coroutinescope

This doesn't have compilation error :

```
suspend fun test() {
    runBlocking {

    }
}
```

This has a compilation error :

```
suspend fun test() {
    launch {

    }
}
```

> Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable
>   because of receiver type mismatch: public fun
>   CoroutineScope.launch(context: CoroutineContext = ..., start:
>   CoroutineStart = ..., block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit): Job
>   defined in kotlinx.coroutines

I don't really understand what is the problem...

Comment: launch requires a scope whereas runBlocking is just a way to block a  thread. So to resolve the error you have to use one of the coroutinescope to launch like  GlobalScope.launch{}

Answer (score 4):

[Coroutines are launched](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html#your-first-coroutine) with `launch` coroutine builder in a context of some [CoroutineScope](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/coroutine-scope.html):

```
fun test() = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
}
```

`launch` - is an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extensions) on `CoroutineScope` object, it is [defined](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html) like this:

```
public fun CoroutineScope.launch(...): Job {}
```

`runBlocking` - is not an extension function, so it can be called as a regular function, it is [defined](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html) like this:

```
public fun <T> runBlocking(...): T {}
```

Comment: does runBlocking not need a coroutinescope?

Comment: @OfekRon runBlocking creates its own eventloop and runs it blocking the thread till all its children finishes. While launch launches coroutine in a context without blocking and the event loop is of context it is running on rather than of itself.